# I want pass book data to the view page to the edit page in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, react-props

I used the prop method but the chrome console said this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props') this is the my whole code of the book details view page

```
  import React,{ useEffect, useState } from 'react'
    import axios from "axios";
    import { variables } from "../../../Veriables";

    const ManageBookView =() => {
    const [book, setBook]= useState([])


    const getData = async () =>{
        try{
            const data = await axios.get(variables.API_URL+"book")
            console.log(data.data);
            setBook(data.data)
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    
  

    useEffect(()=>{
        getData()
    },[])



    async function  deleteClick (id) {
      if(window.confirm('Are you sure ?')){
        let result = fetch(variables.API_URL+'book/'+id,{
            method:'DELETE'
        });
        result = await (await result).json;
        alert('Book Deleted Successfully!')
        getData();
      }
    }


    const editCick = (id) =>{
      this.props.history.push({
        pathname:'/managebookedit/'+id
      })
    }

    return (
    <div>
         {/* Content Wrapper. Contains page content */}
         <div className="content-wrapper">
         
         <div className="content-header">
        <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row mb-2">
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <h1 className="m-0">Book</h1>
        </div>{/* /.col */}
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <ol className="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
            <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/paneladmin">Home</a></li>
            <li className="breadcrumb-item active">Manage Book</li>
          </ol>
        </div>{/* /.col */}
      </div>{/* /.row */}
    </div>{/* /.container-fluid */}
  </div>
            <section className="content">
             <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12">
        <div className="card">
          <div className="card-header">
            <h3 className="card-title">   Manage Book</h3>
            <div className="card-tools">
            <a href="/managebookadd"><button type="button" className="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary btn-sm">        Add Book
                </button></a>
                
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* /.card-header */}
          <div className="card-body table-responsive p-0" style={{height: 500}}>
            <table className="table table-hover text-nowrap">
              <thead>
                  
                <tr>
                  <th>Book ID</th>
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Author</th>
                  <th>Category</th>
                  <th>Availability</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              {book.map((item) =>{
                  return(
                        <tr key={item.book_id}>
                        <td>{item.book_id}</td>
                        <td>{item.book_title}</td>
                        <td>{item.book_author}</td>
                        <td>{item.book_category}</td>
                        <td>{item.book_availability}</td>
                        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-light btn-sm"
                        onClick={()=>editCick(item.book_id)}>Edit</button> </td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-sm"
                        onClick={()=>deleteClick(item.book_id)}>Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          {/* /.card-body */}
        </div>
        {/* /.card */}
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* /.row */}
    </div>
                            
    </section>
    </div>       
    </div>
    )
    }
    export default ManageBookView;
```

I cannot find what is the error of the code, this is the my edit page code how I can pass the the data to the this page

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { variables } from '../../../Veriables';

const ManageBookEdit = (props) => {
    const [book, setBook] = useState({title:'',author:'',category:'',releasedate:'',price:'',description:'',type:'' })
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('')
    const [author, setAuthor] = useState('')
    const [category, setCategory] = useState('')
    const [releasedate, setReleasedate] = useState('')
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('')
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
    const [type, setType] = useState('')
    const url = variables.API_URL+'book/Getbook/'+props.match.param.id;


    const getData = async () =>{
        try{
            const data = await axios.get(url)
            console.log(data.data);
            setBook(data.data)
        }
        catch(e){
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        getData()
    },[])

  return (
    <div>
    {/* Content Wrapper. Contains page content */}
    <div className="content-wrapper">
      {/* Content Header (Page header) */}
      <section className="content-header">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row mb-2">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <h1>Book Add</h1>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <ol className="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/paneladmin">Home</a></li>
                <li className="breadcrumb-item"><a href="/managebook">Book Manage</a></li>
                <li className="breadcrumb-item active">Book Add</li>
              </ol>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>{/* /.container-fluid */}
      </section>
      {/* Main content */}
      <section className="content">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <div className="card card-primary">
              <div className="card-header">
                <h3 className="card-title">Book</h3>
                <div className="card-tools">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-tool" data-card-widget="collapse" title="Collapse">
                    <i className="fas fa-minus" />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputName">Title</label>
                  <input type="text" id="inputName" className="form-control" 
                  value={book.title}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputName">Author</label>
                  <input type="text" id="inputName" className="form-control" 
                  value={book.author}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputName">Category</label>
                  <input type="text" id="inputName" className="form-control" 
                  value={book.category}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputName">Release Date</label>
                  <input type="date" id="inputName" className="form-control" 
                  value={book.releasedate}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputName">Price</label>
                  <input type="number" id="inputName" className="form-control" 
                  value={book.price}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputDescription">Description</label>
                  <textarea id="inputDescription" className="form-control" rows={4} defaultValue={""} 
                  value={book.description}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="inputStatus">Type</label>
                  <select id="inputStatus" className="form-control custom-select"
                  value={book.type}
                  >
                    <option selected disabled>Select one</option>
                    <option value="2" key="2" >Digital</option>
                    <option value="1" key="1" >Printed</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              {/* /.card-body */}
            </div>
            {/* /.card */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-12">
            <a href="#" className="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-success float-right" 
             >Create</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br/>
      </section>
      {/* /.content */}
    </div>
    {/* /.content-wrapper */}
        </div>
  )
}

export default ManageBookEdit
```

this is the error log

[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to help you like this. Could you also provide the exact error log?

Comment: I haved update the my question

Comment: @BavinduDissanayake trying console.log the `props` variable then `props.match` then `props.match.params` and see if there is a data coming back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'props')
>     at editCick (ManageBookView.js:42:1)
>     at onClick (ManageBookView.js:106:1)
>     ... and so on in stacktrace
> ```

This error is informing you that the code is attempting to access `props` from an undefined object, accessing `this.props` throws the error. Not only is `ManageBookView` a React function component, meaning that there is no defined `this` to access a `props` object from, but you've also not provided any `props` object to the component.

```
const ManageBookView = () => { ... }
```

In other words, even if `this` *was* defined, `props` is also undefined, so `props.history` would throw a similar error.

## Solution

Provide the `props` object to your `ManageBooView` component.

Instead of

```
const ManageBookView = () => { ... }
```

use

```
const ManageBookView = (props) => { ... }
```

Ensure that this `ManageBookView` component is actually receiving the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (*`history`, `location`, and `match`*). This is accomplished when `ManageBookView` is:

- Rendered directly by a route component

  ```
   <Route path="...." component={ManageBookView} />
  ```
- Decorated with the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component

  ```
   export default withRouter(ManageBookView);
  ```

Now there is a defined `history` prop.

```
const ManageBookView = (props) => {
  ...

  const editClick = (id) => {
    props.history.push({
      pathname: '/managebookedit/' + id
    });
  }

  ...
};
```

Alternatively you can forego the `props` object (*if it's not referenced elsewhere*) and use the React hooks directly.

Example:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const ManageBookView = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  ...

  const editClick = (id) => {
    history.push({
      pathname: '/managebookedit/' + id
    });
  }

  ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to access `props.match...` and `props.history...` in your code. This only works if the Compent is called/accessed via `<Route>` component from `react-router`.

I suspect you have a parent Component that looks somewhat like this.

```
const Parent = () => {
  return(
   <>
     <ManageBookView/>
     <ManageBookEdit/>
   </>
  )
}
```

But what you really need is like this:

```
const Parent = () => {
  return(
   <Router>
      <Route path="managebookedit" component={ManageBookView}/>
      <Route path="managebookedit/:id" component={ManageBookEdit}/>
   </Router>
  )
}
```

Since you only show the Component themselves and not how they are used, its hard to tell for sure, but probably the error is there.

Check out the [react-router documentation](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) on how to qualify a component to use the props you want to use.